# Power Auatomate/Flow - Attach a Flow to a SharePoint List/Library to trigger or create/update

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I would like to create a new Flow that should trigger on SharePoint item/document create/edit event.
This flow will be a common flow for many SharePoint sites and I would like to programmatically attach these flows to the required lists/libraries across many SharePoint sites.

Is this possible?

How do I go about creating a common flow to be used across multiple SharePoint sites? and can I use CSOM, Rest API, Powershell to attach the flow to the libraries/lists on those sites?

Answer (score 2):

Flow trigger based on site address, so you can't create a common flow to be used across multiple SharePoint sites.

Reference:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/One-Flow-Multiple-Sites/td-p/402223